# Is there a go function for taking user input, but not displaying it onscreen?

Tags: go

Similar to the Konami Code in old videogames, the function would record, for a moment, what the player did, and "watch" for a specific combination.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You'll need to provide more context on the situation you're trying to solve this problem for before anyone can help. Is this for a Go app that's running in a terminal, and you're looking for something like `fmt.Scanln()` that doesn't cause the input to be echoed to the shell?

Comment: If so, one quick option would be to use [x/term's ReadPassword](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/term/+/7a66f970:term.go;l=58) function, which will collect input but not display it. It would not capture input like arrow keys, though.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, [Konami Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code) just hooked keystrokes and monitored the stream of keystrokes looking for a specific sequence in order to activate a "cheat code".

That's a different problem than prompting for input from `stdin`, disabling echo and/or masking the input as it's type and reading it.

If the latter is what you want to do, as in prompting for a password, you might take a look at the package [`x/term`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/term) and its [`term.ReadPassword()`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/term#ReadPassword) function, which

> reads a line of input from a terminal without local echo. This is commonly used for inputting passwords and other sensitive data. The slice returned does not include the `\n`.

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   var n int
   fmt.Scan(&n)
   fmt.Println(n == 9)
}
```

If I enter `9`, the program will print `true`.

https://godocs.io/fmt#Scan